# Loading Huge models (large than 1.5 GB fbx format with one single Mesh element) faster in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have some fbx mesh Models, each including one Single mesh element generated after point cloud scan. The files are bigger than 1.5 GB and I have uploaded them on the bucket by the Chunk Model upload method.

Loading these huge models on forge viewer is slow and moving around after loading is not smooth. To make the loading a little bit faster I have [cached the models](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/disconnected-workflows). But this trick is still not fast enough. Is there any other way to load them more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Forge Viewer is optimized to efficiently render *complex designs*, as in, 3D models with a large amount of relatively simple meshes. If there's just a single mesh with a large amount of triangles, the optimizations have no effect.

I'm thinking about two ways of improving the performance:

1. Use a 3rd party library to simplify the mesh itself
2. Since you said that the mesh is coming from a point cloud, you could consider rendering the point cloud in Forge Viewer directly (using Potree for example: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-potree-demo) instead of the reconstructed mesh

Comment: Hi Petr
Thanks for your reply. I would try to simplify the mesh.